# Hinton's reading list from the removed Coursera MOOC

Tags: deep-learning

Geoffrey Hinton's Coursera MOOC was recently discontinued:
https://twitter.com/geoffreyhinton/status/1085325734044991489?lang=en

The videos however are still available at both on Youtube and on Hinton's webpage:
https://www.cs.toronto.edu/~hinton/coursera_lectures.html

However in his MOOC Hinton also had some papers as required (or recommended, I can't really remember) readings after each lecture. They were generally old, seminal papers which provided some good insights and intuitions and were worth reading IMHO for learning purposes. I couldn't find these papers as a reading list online. Does anyone have this list?